# iterator returned by std::find() is not dereferenceable

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std

This is an insert() function of an implementation of a HashTable with chaining. In order to avoid duplications in the linked_list I ckecked if a value already exists. If it does then I just replace the existing value as it can be seen almost at the end where it comments "update value". That line issues an exception telling me that the iterator is not dereferenceable. Why can't I dereference the iterator returned by std::find()? Is there another way to update the value that was found?

```
virtual void insert(const K& k, const V& v) {
    auto index = hashFctn(k, m_table.capacity());
    if (needsToGrow() || m_table[index].m_list.size() >= m_load_factor) {
        rehash();
        insert(k, v);
    }
    else {
        auto it = std::find(m_table[index].m_list.begin(), 
                            m_table[index].m_list.end(), v);
        if (it != m_table[index].m_list.end()) { // if found add it
            m_table[index].m_flag = flag::IN_USE;
            m_table[index].m_key = k;
            m_table[index].m_list.push_back(v);
            m_nbrOfElements++;
        } else {
            *it = v; // update value if exists
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mention it, but is clear (to me I guess) that the linked list being used is the std::list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
if (it != m_table[index].m_list.end()) { // if found add it
    // Irrelevant...
} else {
    *it = v; // update value if exists
}
```

If the iterator `it` is not the end-iterator you do some irrelevant things. But in the else case the iterator `it` is equal to the end-iterator, and that is not dereferencable. And yet you dereference it.

I think the condition should be the opposite, using `==` instead.

Comment: I think my issues is not understanding well how the STL works. I'm use to write all my stuff instead following my textbooks and all that. So, If not found, will std::find() return end(), otherwise a valid iterator?

Comment: @blade That's true.

Comment: @blade: More precisely, `std::find(x,y, value)` will return `y` if `value` is not found in `x .. std::prev(y)`. That means it can search sub-ranges, and then it will return the end of the sub-range if the value isn't found. It also means you can use `std::find` with old C arrays that don't have an `.end()`  member function.